# Liferay service building fails

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, liferay, liferay-6

I was getting the following error when i tried to use liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0 with my liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1 to build service.xml.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\[username]\Documents\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\build-common-plugin.xml: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\Users\[username]\Documents\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\build-common-plugin.xml:118: No suitable relative path from C:\Users\[username]\Documents\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0\portlets\billingform-portlet to D:\Liferay\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes
```

When I searched for a solution, I found that this issue was solved by using previous sdk version, so I used liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1, created a sample project and tried again, which gave me next error.

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\build-common-plugin.xml:210: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\build-common-plugin.xml:71: D:\bundles\tomcat-7.0.27\lib\ext does not exist.
```

But the thing is the liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0 with liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1 combination worked in another machine. I am a newbie to liferay. Please help and also please tell if any more details are required.

Comment: Make sure you have correctly configured build.username.properties , and you are having your liferay tomcat bundle at proper place. In your case check if D:\bundles\tomcat-7.0.27\lib\ext is correct path.

Comment: No actually there is nothing like D:\bundles. My sdk path is given correctly as D:\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1 in eclipse. I don't know how it comes. If I am right, D:\Liferay\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\lib\ext exists. I don't know where to configure it or how it went wrong.

Comment: Thats why you are facing this issue make sure your sdk is refering to correct liferay bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please configure your local development environemnt properly.
This errors comes when your plugin-sdk is refering to wrong path of liferay-tomcat bundle defined in build.username.properties file.

For proper guidance for Plugins SDK Configuration, Refer to [link](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/leveraging-the-plugins-sdk-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en)

Also never mix-up different Liferay Versions sdk and tomcat.

Regards,

Comment: But what about the first error? It was all the same versions. Will error occur if plugin sdk and portal are in different drives?

Comment: No, different drives cant create problem, but you can give a try to keep plugin sdk in same drives and with short relative path

Comment: Solved. The first issue was due to the liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0 and liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1 being in different drives. Thanks for the link. It was given in there. It is working now.

Comment: @sree if this answer helps you to solve your problem then mark it as answer so others can refer it

Answer (score 2):

The first issue was due to the liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0 and liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1 being in different drives. Once they were put into same drives and upon creating a new project with the new configuration, it worked

Answer (score 1):

For second error

{ie : D:\bundles }

Go to : Windows -- Preferences  -- Server -- Runtime Environment

Add Server runtime environments

In window Edit Server Runtime environment {Liferay Tomcat Runtime}

fill Name, browse Liferay Tomcat directory, Select runtime JRE  .... click Next

you get window, Edit Server Runtime environment {Liferay Tomcat Runtime Bundle}

browse the 3rd field : Liferay Tomcat bundle zip file (required for Ext plugins)
for tomcat zip file 'liferay-portal-tomcat-6.2.0-ce-ga1 . zip'

(ie.  the tomcat bundle you have downloaded for liferay)

Click Finish